# Round Robin Scheduling : Operating System

Tags: operating-system

Let us suppose a scenario where we are given three processes :-

```
P1   ->          (CPU burst = 3ms , arrival time = 0ms) ,
P2   ->          (CPU burst = 4ms , arrival time = 0ms), and 
P3   ->          (CPU burst = 5ms , arrival time = 1.5ms)
```

Now I need to schedule these processes by round robin scheduling with time quantum = 2ms.
Also it is given that I/O operation for each process takes 0.5ms .

So now if P1 gets blocked for an I/O request after 1ms , Will the CPU start executing next process from the ready queue or it will wait till P1 returns from I/O wait as the time quanta is for 2ms and it can still execute for 0.5ms more ?

Also when P3 will arrive  at 1.5ms and assuming that CPU has started execution the next process when P1 got blocked due to I/O and now after 0.5ms of I/O operation completion P1 has come to ready queue .....Which among P1 and P3 will be placed first in the ready queue ?

Comment: Round-robin is exactly that, each process gets it shares, then the next, then the next and so on until the last process where it starts over. If you want to prioritize depending on burst times or other information, then you no longer have a pure round-robin algorithm. As for your question, you're the writer of the OS, it's totally up to you to decide, based on whatever other requirements you have of course. All we can offer is our *opinions* which is why I'm voting to close the question as "primarily opinion-based".